# Stack Overflow Timeline of added Functions

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

Is there a page by Stack Overflow on how it evolved? A timeline of added functions would be nice. It might be interesting to see what ideas are most straightforward (early implemented, more important/desired) to be invented.

Comment: Something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant, It would be nice if the most popular function where highlighted. But this is great.